# Dose TDengine support black quote(``) in identifier?

Tags: tdengine

Dose TDengine support black quote in identifier like mysql?
Besides, if there is a ` in a identifier，how can i use?

Answer (score 0):

yes, I tried black quote in table name, it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).